# Java module glossary

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

What is the difference between all these terms used in the Java module specification?  I can't find a definition of these terms that doesn't circularly reference itself.

- Visible
- Observable
- Accessible

The spec makes such statements as this, but I have not yet figured out what these words actually *mean*:

> Specifically, the host system must limit the ordinary compilation
>   units that would otherwise be observable, to only those that are
>   visible to M

([JLS 11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/jls11.pdf) section 7.3 p.183)

Comment: Can you link where you found this?

Comment: I guess you are a non-native speaker? Just translate the words in your language because they just mean what they mean when using english in general. They are not technical terms. For example: visible means that you're actually be able to see it.

Comment: I'm a native speaker.  "Visible" and "observable" are synonyms.  Can you give an example of something in the Java module system that you can "see" but not "observe"?  Or vice-versa?

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry, just thought that it might be the case :-). Observable for example is best explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

visible for example is best explained with the access modifiers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, in JLS terms like visibility may have different meaning when applied to a compilation unit, or a package, or a type.

Some references where terms are defined in JLS:

- **Observable**:

  - Compilation unit: [§7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3), sentence starting *"The host system determines which compilation units are observable"*.
  - Package: [§7.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.3), first paragraph.
  - *Intuition*: elements that participate in compilation.
- **Visible**:

  - Compilation unit: [§7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3), sentence starting *"The ordinary compilation units that are visible to M"* - note that visibility is defined relative to a module
  - Package: [§7.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.3), sentence starting *"A package is visible to a module M"* - again relative to a module.
  - *Intuition*: elements that are observable from the perspective of a given module considering `requires` and `exports`.
- **Accessible**:

  - General definition: [§6.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)

Additionally, the central new notion since JLS 9 is "**uniquely visible**" ([§7.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.3)), plus the terms "potentially accessible", "reads" / "read by", "associated with". Historically, JLS 9 made a further distinction between "technically observable" and "really observable", which has been dropped as of JLS 11.

Also, historically (up-to JLS 8), "visible" was used in the definition of shadowing ([§6.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)), but this use has been withdrawn in JLS 9.

Finally note, that some of these notions (explicitly or implicitly) pull in definition from the  API in `java.lang.module`.

I suggest to consider these terms as technical terms, not meant to appeal to the intuition of a broader audience, in part because many definitions in JLS reason about "compilation units", which are not necessary for an intuitive understanding. For a comparison of a possible intuitive understanding vs. the JLS-based understand please see Slide #20 of [JDT embraces Java™ 9 - An insiders' view](https://www.eclipsecon.org/europe2017/sites/default/files/slides/JDT_Embraces_Java_9_ECE_2017.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Observable is unrelated to the module system.

In the JLS, the hierarchy goes bottom up, as follows:
1. Observable: The totality of compilation units that a compiler knows about.
2. Visible: All the compilation units in those modules that are read by the module whose code is currently being compiled. What each module reads is driven by `requires` directives. Visibility drives what packages and types are in scope, and affects accessibility.
3. Accessible: The public types in those packages that are exported by one module to another module, as long as packages in the first module are visible to the other module.